# Incremental Backup Solution (Sqlite, MySQL, SQL Server)

Tags: database, backup

I am using Sqlite in a project. Currently I have collected 30 million samples and the size of the database file is around 2 GB!. I am also performing the backup using the sqlite3.exe application automatically every 12 hours. The size of the DB is increasing and I should switch to the incremental-backup solution. I wanted to ask if there is a way to do this for the sqlite DB?

If not, I can migrate to another DBMS (like MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server, ...). Which software can I use to automate this incremental backup process. Is there any free software for this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the necessary field in your table, you could simply change your full backup to something that pulls everything that was created *after* the last pull:

```
-- export.sql.template
sql='SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE SampleID > $lastSampleID'
```

Then you could store the last SampleID after each backup:

```bsh
# in pseudo-code - this will not work as-is
cd /path/to/db
lastSampleID=$(cat lastIDFile)
. export.sql.template
echo $sql > export.sql
sqlite db.sqlite --run-script export.sql > backups/$currentDate
lastSampleID=$(get-last-id-from-file backups/$currentDate)
echo $lastSampleID > lastIDFile
```